# angle_0 in joints gazebo

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to know please what does angle_0 present in joint description in gazebo??
Is it an offset? Where is it defined? and how to modify it?
Thank you very much

[C:\fakepath\Capture du 2020-11-06 15-58-56.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16046746957596299.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26064/angle_0-in-joints-gazebo/) by [sana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34096/sana/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just a guess, but that's probably the result of `GetPosition(0)` so it would be the position/coordinate (which for revolute joint is angle) of the first axis of the joint. Joints can have multiple axes (revolute2, ball, universal, etc.)

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2020-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34096/sana/) on 2020-11-12**:
Thank you! You have reason. angle_0 displays the actual joint position in gazebo (radian).